# Any way to access a lexical let variable outside of the let?

Tags: variables, let-binding, lexical-binding, scope, monkey-patching

I need to retrieve a local, lexical, runtime variable from a function, but I'm unable to modify the function to return it because it is from an external library. The variable I'm unable to reach is `link-end`.

```
(defun org-element-link-parser ()
  (let ((link-end) ...)
  ...
  (setq link-end (something))
  ...))
```

Language features I've looked into don't seem to be able to help, *advising* functions is basically a wrapper, and as to *hooks*, `org-element-link-parser` doesn't have hooks. I tried defining link-end in global scope, but it didn't change after the function quit.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that and you shouldn't even try: `let` blocks are meant to define variables that are local in scope and limited in lifetime - they spring into existence when the block is entered and they go *POOF* when the block is exited.

Instead, you should call the function and deduce what you need from what the function returns. In this case:

```el
(setq my-link-end (org-element-property :end (org-element-link-parser)))
```

The `:end` property of the element is actually after any white space that is trailing the link, so if you don't want that, you will need to back up:

```el
(setq my-link-end
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char (org-element-property :end (org-element-link-parser)))
          (skip-chars-backward " \t")
          (point)))
```

And there should probably be some error checking to make sure that you are at a link, otherwise the result of the `org-element-property` call will be `nil` and `goto-char` will barf.

Comment: I should've read the org-element-link-parser definition more carefully, I knew about :end, thought I didn't want it, but didn't realize that applying (skip-chars-backward " \t") on it is equivalent to `link-end`. In this case I won't need to expose a variable inside a let inside a lexical function, but I'll leave the question up just in wonder if it's possible.

Comment: In a lot of programming contexts I might feel the need to tweak one library function, and I find an extreme poverty of tools for that (short of redefining the function and falling behind on updates) in all programming languages I know about.

Comment: Emacs Lisp, like some other lisps, implements a general-purpose `advice` system (two of them, in fact) which is as good a system of "tweaking" other functions as I've encountered.  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html documents the newer of the two systems.  Advising functions is generally a last resort, but the ability is a blessing when you need it.

Comment: I see you've indicated in another comment that advice is inadequate for your purpose, and I'm not trying to argue otherwise; I'm just saying that "an extreme poverty of tools" isn't an accurate description when you have (a) the ability to redefine functions; (b) the ability to advise them in many different ways; and (c) if you really, really, really want to (and you shouldn't), the ability to manipulate code as data.  Compared to many languages, this is a veritable wealth of tools.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be split into a general answer to the question as stated in the caption

> Any way to access a lexical let variable outside of the let?

and an answer to your specific problem in the description, how to access `link-end` in `org-element-link-parser`. The general answer does not work for your specific problem since you do not want to modify `org-element-link-parser`.

The short answer to both parts is: Yes, you can.

First, I want to address your specific problem:

An excerpt from `org-element-parser`:

```el
(defun org-element-link-parser ()
  (let (... link-end ...)
    (cond
     ...
     ;; all cases look like the following:
     ((looking-at ...)
      ...
      (setq link-end (match-end 0))
      ...
      )
     )
    ;; After the `cond':
    (save-excursion
      (setq post-blank
        (progn (goto-char link-end) (skip-chars-forward " \t")))
      (setq end (point)))
    (list 'link
      (list ;; The element properties:
       ...
       :end end
       ...))))
```

So, `end` is essentially `link-end`, only that there is the additional operation `(skip-chars-forward " \t")`.

If you want to retrieve the value of `link-end` you have to reverse the effect of `(skip-chars-forward " \t")` to the property `:end`. Luckily the number of chars skipped by `(skip-chars-forward " \t")` is saved as property `:post-blank`.

I.e., with point at a link, do:

```el
(when-let ((link (org-element-link-parser))
       (post-blank (org-element-property :post-blank link))
       (end (org-element-property :end link))
       (link-end (- end post-blank)))
  link-end)
```

---

Now, the answer to the general question

> Any way to access a lexical let variable outside of the let?

Yes, define setter/getter functions within the let for accessing the variable.
The variable will be in the lexical environment of these functions.

```el
(declare-function my-set nil)
(declare-function my-get nil)

(defun my-function ()
  "Function with the lexically bound variable `my-var'.

We define `my-set' and `my-get' here."
  (let ((my-var 1))
    (fset 'my-set
      (lambda (value)
        (setq my-var value)))
    (fset 'my-get
      (lambda ()
        my-var)))
  "The function could also return the lambdas.")

(format
 "The return value of `my-function': %s
The value of `my-var': %d
Setting `my-var' to 2: %d
The value after `my-set': %d"
 (my-function)
 (my-get)
 (my-set 2)
 (my-get))
```

The resulting output is:

The return value of `my-function': The function could also return the lambdas.
The value of `my-var': 1
Setting `my-var' to 2: 2
The value after `my-set': 2